# gmail login using angular 2 not login properly after logout

Tags: javascript

when I first time login with gmail account then it properly works but when I am logout my account though my app then it clears localstorage the logout process and G-mail-signIn button rendered again and but when I am click on it then it doesn't work i dont understand what happens

#### login process

```
login html page

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12" *ngIf="isLogin">
    <div id="{{googleLoginButtonId}}"></div>
</div>
```

#### login component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("initCalled");
    // Converts the Google login button stub to an actual button.
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance({
        client_id: '656224112655-n9t6aesubdfpdtb1vjk0rnh9r6np2ug7.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        hosted_domain: ConstantValues.hosted_domain,
        scope: 'profile'
      });
      // auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      //var dataSigned = auth2.isSignedIn;
      //console.log("auth2-------", dataSigned.Ab);
      //console.log("dataSigned-----", auth2)
    });
  }

  // Angular hook that allows for interaction with elements inserted by the
  // rendering of a view.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    gapi.signin2.render(
      this.googleLoginButtonId,
      {
        "onSuccess": this.onGoogleLoginSuccess,
        "onFailure": this.onSignInFailure,
        "scope": "profile",
        "theme": "dark"
      });
    setTimeout(function () {
      this.googleLoginButtonId = this.googleLoginButtonId
    },
      1000);
  }

  // Triggered after a user successfully logs in using the Google external
  // login provider.
  onGoogleLoginSuccess = (loggedInUser) => {
    this._zone.run(() => {
      this.userAuthToken = loggedInUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
      this.user.userName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
      this.user.userMail = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
      localStorage.setItem('userMail', this.user.userMail);
      localStorage.setItem('userName', this.user.userName);
      console.log("Successfull--------Login", this);
      localStorage.setItem('isLogin', "true");
      this.broadcastValue.alertUserLoginOrLogout(true);
      console.log("at the tym of login success");
      console.log(this);
    });
  }
  onSignInFailure = (loggedInUser) => {
    console.log("Login Failed!!");
    this.broadcastValue.alertUserLoginOrLogout(false);
    this.toaster.showError('Please login with daffodilsw.com!', 'Login Failure!');
  }
}

//logout process

  signOutFunc = () => {
    console.log("-Router-", this);
    localStorage.removeItem('role');
    localStorage.removeItem('userName');
    localStorage.removeItem('userMail');
    localStorage.setItem('isLogin', "false");
    this.broadcastValue.alertUserLoginOrLogout(false);
    this.broadcastValue.alertRoleExistance(false);
  }
```

Comment: do you get any error in console ?

Comment: how about using firebase auth? like in this tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.com/angular-2-authentication-made-easy-with-firebase-246c282d9ef8#.3t3f7f39f

Comment: get an error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at G_ (cb=gapi.loaded_1:90)